# Python: How to sort a list of objects using attrgetter with case insensitivity

Tags: python, key, case-insensitive, attr, sorting

```
self.data = sorted(self.data, key=attrgetter('word'))
```

self.data is a list of Word objects. Word objects have 'word', 'definition', 'example' and 'difficulty' attributes. I want to sort by the 'word' strings of each Word object, and the code above does that except it's not case insensitive. How would I go about making the sorting case insensitive?

I've tried the solutions from another question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414201/how-do-i-make-this-sorting-case-insensitive), but when I tried it, it said "TypeError: 'Word' object is not subscriptable". What could I do to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own `key` function:

```
self.data = sorted(self.data, key = lambda w: w.word.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
self.data = sorted(self.data, key=lambda w: attrgetter('word')(w).lower())
```

Though, with that you would probably be much better off simply using:

```
self.data = sorted(self.data, key=lambda w: w.word.lower()
```