# attrgetter: Altering Default Order When Sorting by Object Attribute

Tags: python, sorting, attributes, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am using the `attrgetter` function from Python 3's `operator` module in order to sort a list of objects (hits). Each object has 12 attributes, and my sorting function can be fed any of them in order to sort the list in whatever way is needed. The attributes I am interested in sorting on contain strings. Here is the relevant snippet from my code.

```
from operator import attrgetter
...
def sort_hits_by_attribute(hits, attribute, backwards = False):
    """Takes a lits of hits and sorts them by some attribute.
    """
    return sorted(hits, key = attrgetter(attribute), reverse = backwards)
```

Here is an example of a "hit" object, with its attributes.

```
  name: ...
  entity_1: coffee cultivation
  entity_2: ...
  full_statement: ...
  category: ...
  rule: ...
  syn_configs: ...
  lex_conditions: ...
  sentence_number: ...
  close_call: False
  message: ...
  id: 119
```

If I sort my list of objects by the attribute `entity_1`, then the above object is sorted *after* an instance whose `entity_1` field begins with an upper case letter: e.g., "Coffee" or even "Zoo."

I would like to use a function something like `casefold()`, so that upper case letters are sorted adjacent to and after their lower case counterparts. However, `casefold()` is only valid for strings, so using `key = attrgetter(attribute).casefold()` returns an AttributeError.

How can I preserve the functionality of `sort_hits_by_attribute()` – i.e., sorting by an attribute passed in during the function call – but force Python to use a different ordering {aAbBcCdDeE...} when doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7656440/10713931), thanks to @KylePDavis, who provided a generalized solution where the attribute can be passed in as an argument. The key is defining the key using a `lambda` function.

My code now looks as follows. Note the input check to verify (1) that the list is not empty and (2) whether the attribute of interest is indeed of a type (`str`) that can be sorted using `casefold()`.

```
def sort_hits_by_attribute(hits, attribute, backwards=False):
    """Takes a lits of hits and sorts them by some attribute.

    For instance, group duplicate relation hits together by sorting
    on full_statement.
    """

    if hits:
        if isinstance(attrgetter(attribute)(hits[0]), str):
            return sorted(hits, 
                key = lambda A: attrgetter(attribute)(A).casefold(), 
                reverse = backwards)
        else:
            return sorted(hits, 
                key = attrgetter(attribute), 
                reverse = backwards)
```

I have not marked this question as a duplicate because the cited question's favorited answer is not the answer that was important specifically for this case.